# Admin identity error when joining new peers to a channel

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger

I'm really tired with this issue.
Please and Please explain how I can solve this problem to me if you know. I'm begging

I'm working on "Fabcar" sample which has 1 peer / 1 orderer / 1 ca server in the fabric-samples folder.

I wanted to add 2 more peers to the network and join them to the channel(which is called my channel)

So I've modified 3 files: crypto-config.yaml, docker-compose.yml, start.sh (in the basic-network folder) appropriately.

I'm also done producing crypto materials for the new 2 peers with the cryptogen tool.

But the thing is that when I executed "peer channel join -b myblock.block" in peer0.org1.example.com container in order to join those new peers to the channel, this error message is shown:

[This error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fd5xJ.png)

It says "JoinChain" request failed authorization check for channel [mychannel]: [Failed verifying that proposal's creator satisfies local MSP principal during channelless check policy with policy [Admins]: [This identity is not an admin]]))

I've also tried that command both inside and outside peer0.org1.example with docker exec command, and did with sudo and nothing works well.

It seems that I need to initiate the transaction with the admin's cert, but I really have no idea how to make it and how to resolve this authorization issue.

Please anyone who knows how to deal with this issue explain this to me in detail.

I've suffered from this problem for a very long time. I'm really desperate.

I'd really appreciate if you tell me how. Looking forward to your response. Thank you.

Comment: If this two peers are from different org, more things should be done.https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/release-1.1/docs/source/channel_update_tutorial.rst

Comment: Hey There, can you tell me how did you generated the crypto-artifacts for the new Peer ?

Answer (score 1):

The error message is the tell: `[This identity is not an admin]`. You need to be using the identity of the admin for a given peer/org in order to execute the `peer channel join` command.

The way that cryptogen creates the crypto material is to populate a directory tree of a specific structure. For the admin certificate, you need to be using this identity:

`fabric-samples/basic-network/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp`

in order to be the admin for Org1. The script that creates the channel and joins the one peer in the default sample is done with the command here:

https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/f05a132586ae9ca7ce86b9e56ae4bd3b084bc959/basic-network/start.sh#L26

Comment: Hello. Thank you for your help. I just tried initiating the join channel proposal with the certificate, the same as the last line in the code you sent, but I got another error which I've seen before. It says "Cannot create ledger from genesis block, LedgerID already exists."

Comment: I thought that error was because I made peer0 execute the command, so when I made peer1(which is one of new peers and is supposed to join the channel) execute it with $docker exec peer1.org1.example.com peer join -b mychannel.block, "mychannel.block: no such file or directory" error is shown. I think this is because endorsers and orderer don't know who peer1 is(and peer1 doesn't have myblock.block). Could you please tell me how to make it to me, if you don't mind? I appreciate your help again.

Comment: Thank you @christo4ferris. I'm encountering the same issue trying to join a peer to a channel via the node SDK. Getting the same [This identity is not an admin] message, but I can't work out how via the SDK to specify the identity. Do you know? Many thank!

Answer (score 1):

This issue is due to the access level of the credentials you are using.
You need to be an admin to add a peer to a channel, so you have access to to the system chaincode cscc.

Another possible issue is that in the network configuration (usually the configtx.yaml file) there is some policy resticting your access to join the peer to the channel, if you'd like I can take a look in your configtx file and see if I can help.

As you are using the Fabcar example and it's called with Node SDK you can add the peer also using SDK.

Please try it:

Instantiate a Fabric Client object and enroll an admin user. You can do it in your script based in Fabcar's enrollAdmin.js, as I will explain

In Fabcar's enrollAdmin.js line 72 you can see this line:

```
console.log('Assigned the admin user to the fabric client ::' + admin_user.toString());
```

Start from here, inside the "then" that starts in line 71.
You have to enroll the identity as an admin usng the method

```
fabric_client.setAdminSigningIdentity(pk, cert, MSPID);
```

The pk parameter is the admin private key, cert is his certificate and the MSPID is the one you specified for his organization in the configtx.yaml file.

you can get the pk and cert using the file system module from Node addins the following:

```
let fs = require('fs');

let cert = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'PATH_TO_CERT/CERT_NAME.pem'))
let pk = fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'PATH_TO_PK','PK_NAME'))
```

The usual path to the admin certificate is

```
/fabric-samples/basic-network/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/admincerts
```

And to the private key is:

```
/fabric-samples/basic-network/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp/keystore
```

Now you just added the admin identity to your clients's instance, if everything is ok you need to create a peer instance with your peer's address as the following example:

```
peer=fabric_client.newPeer(grpc://localhost:7051);
```

Don't forget to use the grpc protocol, and if tls is enabled you have to use grpcs.

Now create a channel instance of your channel using the channel id as parameter:

```
let channel_i=fabric_client.newChannel('mychannel')
```

Then create a request to the channel genesis (config) block:

```
let orderer = fabric_client.newOrderer(ORDERER_URL);//the urlalso with grpc protocol
let tx_id=fabric.client.newTransactionID(true); //true means it's an administrative request
let g_request={
    txId: tx_id,
    orderer : orderer
}
```

Finally, make the block request, then use it to join the channel:

```
channel_i.getGenesisBlock(g_request).then((block) =>{

    tx_id = fabric.client.newTransactionID(true);
    let j_request = {
          targets : peer,
          block : block,
          txId : tx_id,
     };

    // send genesis block to the peer
        return channel_i.joinChannel(j_request, 10000).then((results) =>{
            if(results[0].response.status == 200) {
                // join successful
                console.log("Join successful!!!");
            } else {
                // not good
                console.log("Error:: "+ results);
                throw  results;
            }
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

For the admin identity error, copy that identity signedcert into Org MSP admincerts folder and then generate the channel tx file.

Answer (score 0):

This issue could be occurred due to wrong config of **CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH**

Please check yaml file. The *CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH* should be

> /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/crypto-config/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp

The above org1 is for sample, you can check with your org name.